# Cannot build and deploy default Azure Web Bot

Tags: botframework, kudu

I have created a Web Bot in Azure. The bot is using Bot SDK v4.
When building the bot in the online code editor using build.cmd I get the following error:

```
Kudu sync from: 'D:\local\Temp\___deployTemp8666' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\.'
Copying file: 'BasicBot.deps.json'
Copying file: 'BasicBot.runtimeconfig.json'
Copying file: 'web.config'
Ignoring: .deployment
Ignoring: deploy.cmd
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\home\site\artifacts\manifest'
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\local\AppData\npm\kuduSync.cmd" -v 50 -f "D:\local\Temp\___deployTemp8666" -t "D:\home\site\wwwroot\." -n "D:\home\site\wwwroot\..\artifacts\manifest" -p "D:\home\site\wwwroot\..\artifacts\manifest" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

I have used the default Web Bot template v4 in Azure and have not made any changes to the code, whatsoever.
Shouldn't the app be able to compile and deploy out of the box?

Kind regards,
Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the reason for this error. It must be a bug in the Bot Creation template in Azure. What I saw was simply that the "artifacts" folder hadn't been created. Once I created it manually, it all worked fine.